# mongoose complex population

Tags: javascript, mongoose

i did find a post by id and i did console log output and it was that:

```
{ comments: [ 5c263bf01b764a11c479f69c, 5c263c41133ace1655edee76 ],
  _id: 5c263bc61b764a11c479f69b,
  title: 'good laptop',
  category: 'Laptop',
  brand: 'dell',
  Condition: 'Good Condition',
  image: 'https://avisassets.abgemea.com/.imaging/flexibleIntroLarge/dms/DMS/local/ZA/fleet/fleet-page/luxury-cars-feature.jpg',
  price: 2000,
  priceState: 'Negociable',
  city: 'Algiers',
  phone: '71717171555',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  description: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
  date: '28/11/2018',
  userId: 5c25344c321f0d5a777ace00,
  __v: 2 }
```

i did read mongoose documentation about `populate` but i didn't figure out how to populate the `userId`and also populate `comments` and the nested `userId` under the `comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `userId` is a field in your `Posts` schema, you can do it this way:

```
Posts.findOne({ id: 'your-post-id' })
  .populate('userId')
  .populate({ path: 'comments',
              populate: { path: 'userId',
                          model:'User' }
           })
  .exec(callback);
```

Your schemas should be similar to this:

```
var postsSchema = new Schema({
    comments: { type: [Schema.ObjectId], ref: 'Comment' },
    userId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    ...
});
var commentsSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)